# How should I check for a condition and when not true, repeat a previous step?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying the beginner level of python code, where I want the project to check if a certain variable has been given either 1 or 0. 1 and 0 represent the selection of addition or subtraction.

The code is given below:

```
print("This program can be used to add and subtract")
x=int(input("x:"))
y=int(input("y:"))
print("Choose for addition :1 or subtraction 0")
z = int(input("z:"))

if z==1:
    print("Addition selected.")
    a= x+y
    print("The sum of ",y,"and",x,"is",a)
elif z ==0:
    print("Subtraction selected.")
    a= x-y
    print("The difference between ",y,"and",x,"is",a)
else:
    print("Kindly input either 1 or 0")
```

I want to run it so that when z is not equal to 1 or zero, it redirects user to pick one value for z again, till the correct value isn't selected!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the first half of the code in a method so that you can reuse it. Like this:

```
z = 0

def getInput():
    print("This program can be used to add and subtract")
    x=int(input("x:"))
    y=int(input("y:"))
    print("Choose for addition :1 or subtraction 0")
    z = int(input("z:"))
```

The z needs to be outside of the method so that it can be called from outside of the method also.

Then, you can change your code to

```
else:
    getInput()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place the entire program into a `while` loop. Something like:

```
z = 0
while z != 2
    print("This program can be used to add and subtract")
    x=int(input("x:"))
    y=int(input("y:"))
    print("Choose for addition :1 or subtraction 0". Enter 2 to quit)
    z = int(input("z:"))

    if z==1:
        print("Addition selected.")
        a= x+y
        print("The sum of ",y,"and",x,"is",a)
     elif z ==0:
        print("Subtraction selected.")
        a= x-y
        print("The difference between ",y,"and",x,"is",a)
     else:
        print("Kindly input either 1 or 0") 
print "Good Bye!"
```

(sorry for any syntax errors, my python is a bit rusty)

Answer (score 0):

you can use indefinite while loop, and a break statement

```
print("This program can be used to add and subtract")
x=int(input("x:"))
y=int(input("y:"))
print("Choose for addition :1 or subtraction 0")
z = -1
while True:
   z=int(input('enter number'))
   if z==1 or z==0:
       break;
if z==1:
    print("Addition selected.")
    a= x+y
    print("The sum of ",y,"and",x,"is",a)
elif z ==0:
    print("Subtraction selected.")
    a= x-y
    print("The difference between ",y,"and",x,"is",a)
```